# MPMoviePlayerController control visible when starting movie

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have strange problem with `MPMoviePlayerController`. When movie starts , top bar with done button & controls remain visible for few seconds.Then disappears.

I am using

```
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[player setFullscreen:YES];
```

player is an object of `MPMoviePlayerController`

I just want movie to play in full screen with top bar & controls hidden

& become visible only if user taps the screen

I am using iOS 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

before starting the video

```
player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

and when movie starts playing then set

```
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

You can get play callback from MPMediaPlayback protocol.

Comment: How can we check that movie started playing.Where should I use None style.Though I tried

Comment: player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleNone;
 after initialzing the url.

Comment: Actually I was not putting the ControlStyle not in order as you told.I made changes, it worked, thanx Sanniv

Comment: Documentation for getting notification : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html , try looking for MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification in this page. I guess you know how to register notifications...