# How to display controls and seekbar of MPMoviePlayerController always iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want controls and seekbar of MPMoviePlayerController should be visible all the time. Currently controls and seekbar hides after specific time. Please let me know solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the answer here:
[MPMoviePlayerController control visible when starting movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285151/mpmovieplayercontroller-control-visible-when-starting-movie)

You need to manipulate the `controlStyle` of your `MPMoviePlayerController` class

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/controlStyle

Comment: This is how it is working right now, when we tap on player view, controls become visible and tapping again remove the controls. I want those to visible all the time if we tap again and again on player view.

Comment: @FarukhZahoor any luck?...I want same things you are asking